# Getting error when redirecting stdout output to stderr stream from an external plugin

Tags: shell, batch-file

I am running a plugin from a client. The plugin executes scripts that are on a Windows machine. I am executing a .bat script which in turn executes a Java program which executes an SQL query. The plugin only captures stderr stream and I wish to capture the output of the SQL query in the stderr stream. I am using the below command from the plugin to do so:

```
C:\Users\dynamntr2\Documents\GenericExecutionPlugin\Test1.bat 1>&2
```

But I am getting the below error:

```
execute method: exception was thrown when executing command 
'C:\Users\dynamntr2\Documents\GenericExecutionPlugin\Test1.bat 1>&2'.
Stack trace is 'java.lang.RuntimeException exception occurred. 
Message = 'Unexpected end of file from server'; 
Stacktrace is '''
```

The command is returning the output of the SQL query on the screen when I run locally from the windows machine. How do I fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I am not really sure how you start your batch file. I think you start it from a java program.

If this is the case, the command seems wrong. The redirector operators and stream identifiers are handled by a `cmd` instance that has to create the requested stream configuration to then start the batch file.

That means that to use this approach, you must not execute the batch command, but a `cmd` instance that creates the redirection and executes the batch file.

```
cmd.exe /c "C:\Users\dynamntr2\Documents\GenericExecutionPlugin\Test1.bat 1>&2"
```

Comment: The command "C:\Users\dynamntr2\Documents\GenericExecutionPlugin\Test1.bat" works fine through the plugin. It is failing only when I add 1>&2 to the command. The following command also failed with the same error: cmd.exe /c "C:\Users\dynamntr2\Documents\GenericExecutionPlugin\Test1.bat 1>&2"